# Метод загрузки фотографий в Instagram? Или как загрузить фото на сервер при больших нагрузках

Tags: android, node.js, tcp

Есть написанный мессенджер Android + node.js. Нагрузка распределяется в соответствии загруженности между cluster. Выдерживает при тестах до **100 тыс активных** пользователей(только текст).

А загрузка фото и файлов делается с помощью обычного post запроса через php скрипт.

Когда запускаешь тест на загрузку массива фото. Начинаются сильные тормоза. Стек переполняется и всё крашится.

Вопрос: Как организовать правильно загрузку файлов на сервер, не загружая при этом сервер(например, как в Instagram)? Может быть лучше файлы бить на кусочки и передавать по tcp с сообщениями/определенным интервалом? Приветствуется любой опыт высоких нагрузок.

Спасибо.

Comment: насколько я знаю, используют отдельные медиа-серверы. amazonavs вроде на этом специализируется

Comment: не хотелось бы стороннему серверу отдавать информацию о пользователях

Comment: и ненадо. Можно просто использовать его, как медиа хранилище. А у себя в БД хранить соответствие имени файла в этом медиахранилище конкретному пользователю

Comment: хотелось бы, чтобы всё было на своем сервере

Comment: что значит "на своем"? Вы же его орендуете? Так же само орендуйте и сервер для медиа контента. Такой же самый *свой*.

Comment: в планах свой дата центр организовать как вконтакте

Comment: использование сторонних сервисов не пойдет, давайте думать другой вариант

Comment: значит выделите один из серверов в датацентре под медиа. Я не вижу проблемы.